# Посоветуйте язык/фреймворк

Tags: javascript, html, c++, python, qt

Мне нужно сделать наглядно (графически) перевод из одной сс (системы счисления) в другую. На C++ я реализовал все (в командной строке) но сказали сделать наглядно. Думаю сделать по дефолту то есть деление столбиком и по пунктом.

Какой язык лучше использовать ? Я думал об QT как вариант Html + css + javascript (что-то типа веб приложения) не знаю что выбрать =\ посоветуйте пожалуйста.
Со следующей недели буду изучать Python мб на нем ?

Comment: для *простейшей* задачи, если всё равно Python придётся учить, можно попробовать его на клиенте использовать, к примеру http://www.skulpt.org/ или Jupyter notebook создать с интерактивным widget (комбинация html+python), [примеры](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/)—тогда и с телефона, планшета, любой OS можно использовать и минимум кода. Вместо деления столбиком, можно http://pythontutor.com/ попробовать (хотя не ясно, что слово "наглядно" означает в этом случае).

Comment: @jfs мне нужно сделать примерно так же как и тут)
[ссылка](http://calculatori.ru/perevod-chisel.html)
там можно нажать "показать как получилось" и мне под словом наглядно нужно сделать что-то типо такого) Мне посоветовали делать на JS что-то типо веб-приложения/плагина

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вас есть хоть какой-нибудь опыт в web, то можете на нем сделать - это вполне себе быстро и не требует особых затрат.

Если брать ЯП, то C# отлично подходит, можете формочку прямо в VC состряпать.
Но язык здесь большой роли не играет, задача то на коленке решается.

Все зависит от того, какой наглядности требует тот, кто дал Вам это задание.